# What's the downside to styling Android Views by subclassing in Java as opposed to using the XML style system?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I'm forever fighting with balancing bloated xml layouts vs difficult-to-grasp style.xml. So I'm starting to experiment with just creating a new widget for each type of input field. For instance, I have a blue button that I use everywhere in the app, so I'm making a `BlueButton` that just does what I want in its constructor:

```
public class BlueButton extends AppCompatButton {
    public BlueButton(Context context) {        this(context,null);    }
    public BlueButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {        this(context, attrs, 0);    }
    public BlueButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_button_blue_gradient);
        setTextSize(COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,20);
        setAllCaps(true);
        setGravity(CENTER); setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,android.R.color.white));
    }
}

        <app.ui.widget.BlueButton
            android:id="@+id/myButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="My Happy Blue Button"
            />
```

This seems so obvious, that I'm sure I'm missing something. What's the downside to doing this that I'm missing?

Comment: Basically, I'm very much for using custom Views like your BlueButton or also more complex ViewGroups with some simple logic (e.g. a calculator surface) For me, the biggest risk is that you may find yourself with a zoo of special Buttons of various colors and sizes which clutter up the project unnecessarily - some balance has to be achieved here as well as with the "layout vs. style" question. Plus there is that pattern "composition over inheritance". It seems to me that sticking with styles/ themes/ overlays is more like using composition.

Comment: Would reserve to code to customize behavior, not looks.

Comment: @zapl care to discuss why? If we were talking about a system as powerful as CSS I'd have to agree, but Android Styling is difficult and arcane. Java is so much more straightforward and powerful. Also, if you look at Anko Layouts, there is so much more you can do in code. https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Layouts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BlueButton` class you posted could instead be a style resource:

```
<style name="BlueButton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_button_blue_gradient</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

It seems likely from your question that you already knew this, but I say it so that we can compare the style resource to the Java code you posted.

In one case, you change the tag you're using:

```
<app.ui.widget.BlueButton ... />
```

In the other case, you add a `style` attribute:

```
<Button style="@style/BlueButton" ... />
```

These don't seem significantly different to me. You can use IDE tools like "find usages" equally easily on a Java class as you can a style resource. So the only question is whether you think style resources are "harder to manage" than a Java class.

Personally, I don't think they are.

Perhaps you don't like having a huge `styles.xml` file with 500 style definitions in it. If this is the case, then I would say that the right approach is to split your `styles.xml` file up into smaller files, and not to create Java classes. You could, after all, have a `bluebutton.xml` file that only had this one style resource in it.

---

Edit: I'm putting this above the below because I think it's even more important. Too bad I didn't think of it the first time around.

As for downsides, creating View subclasses like your `BlueButton` will "break" the attributes you set in the constructor. Let's say I want to use `BlueButton`, but this time I want black text instead of white. Everything else is very "blue-button-ish", but I can't write this:

```
<app.ui.widget.BlueButton
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    ... />
```

My button will still have white text in this case! That's because the `super` constructor parses the attributes, but then the `BlueButton` constructor overrides them. If, on the other hand, I had used a style:

```
<Button
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    style="@style/BlueButton"
    ... />
```

My button will have black text now.

---

Another argument I have against creating View subclasses as opposed to using styles is that the View subclass has no way to enforce that the instances match the given styling over the lifetime of the app. Nothing is stopping me from adding a `BlueButton` to my layout but then calling `button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.foo)` later on.

Using styles makes it more explicit that this is just the *initial* state of the button. Then I'm never tempted to check if my button has a blue background by doing something like `if (button instanceof BlueButton)`, which isn't even guaranteed to work (as described above).

**tl;dr**: Making View subclasses isn't terrible, but I think it's marginally worse than using style attributes.

Comment: Good point about java constructor overriding and making it impossible to tweak the button with xml. However, that _could_ end up being an advantage and discourage spreading the info about how the button is styled outside of Java. Also, it's possible to end up with dozens (hundreds?) of little classes that style various aspects of the UI, but is that really worse than doing it in XML? In Java I have very powerful tools for inheritance and composition, far superior to what I have in the Android style system.